# Facebook login boilerplate code is bugged

Tags: javascript, facebook-sdk-4.0, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have 2 problems with the code Meta gave for the [Business Whatsapp API / embedded flow integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/embedded-signup/embed-the-flow/)

I'm getting two errors:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: `fbq` is not defined
   launchWhatsAppSignup
2. The call inside `FB.login` is not being waited - the I click the login, the dialog opens and immediately the code inside the fail callback is executed. This is the main problem since I can just comment the `fbq` line, but I need to read the login dialog response in order to access the token.

How to resolve the issue so that WhatsApp embedded signup can be implemented?.

The `fbq` should work since the SDK is being loaded, and the callback should be waited.

This is the HTML code of the button

```html
<button onclick="launchWhatsAppSignup()" style="background-color: #1877f2; border: 0; border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; height: 40px; padding: 0 24px;">Login with Facebook</button>
```

And the JavaScript for that is as follows:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  // JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
  console.log(facebookMetaData.metaAPPID);
  FB.init({
    appId: facebookMetaData.metaAPPID, // Meta App ID
    cookie: true, // enable cookies
    xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
    version: "v19.0", //Graph API version
  });
};

// Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
(function (d, s, id) {
  var js,
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");

// Facebook Login with JavaScript SDK
function launchWhatsAppSignup() {
  // Conversion tracking code
  fbq &&
    fbq("trackCustom", "WhatsAppOnboardingStart", {
      appId: facebookMetaData.metaAPPID,
      feature: "whatsapp_embedded_signup",
    });

  // Launch Facebook login
  FB.login(
    function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        const code = response.authResponse.code;
        // The returned code must be transmitted to your backend,
        // which will perform a server-to-server call from there to our servers for an access token
      } else {
        console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
      }
    },
    {
      config_id: facebookMetaData.configurationID, // configuration ID goes here
      response_type: "code", // must be set to 'code' for System User access token
      override_default_response_type: true, // when true, any response types passed in the "response_type" will take precedence over the default types
      //   extras: {
      //     setup: {
      //       ... // Prefilled data can go here
      //     }
      //   }
    },
  );
}
```